# RestKit: "mappingsByKeyPath" mutated while being enumerated

Tags: dictionary, restkit

when i request multiple request to my web service , i received
this error

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException', reason: '*** Collection <__NSCFDictionary: 0x8a32310> was mutated
>   while being enumerated.'
>   *** First throw call stack: (0x1b02052 0x1f95d0a 0x1b01c21 0x5a38c 0x5342b 0x53b1a 0x53baa 0x13534e6 0x1353457 0x9b455ed9 0x9b4596de)

I think this is releated "singleton RKObjectManager" in RestKit when it receives multiple responses from web service. But i can't find solution for it.
Please help me solve this problem. Thanks advatange!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and it turned out I was mutating mappings while parsing objects. For more info checkout the comment on this github issue:

https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/issues/345#issuecomment-8072999